# Xamarin/Android - Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin, push-notification

I'm trying to implement push notifications through Azure Notification Hubs. I'm using Xamarin.Forms 4.8.0.1269 and Visual Studio 2019.

I've made all the configurations:

- Azure suscription;
- Firebase configurations;
- Created notification hub and all configurations;
- Target Android version for the project is Android 9.0 (pie);
- Added required NuGet packages;
- Added the Google Services JSON File;
- AndroidManifest.xml changed;
- MainActivity changed to check for Google Play Services and stuff;
- Added a FirebaseService class.

Then, when I run the app, after the splash screen I get this exception before any chance of debuggig.

```
Java.Lang.RuntimeException: 'Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: com.google.firebase.components.MissingDependencyException: Unsatisfied dependency for component Component<[class com.google.firebase.remoteconfig.RemoteConfigComponent]>{2, type=0, deps=[Dependency{anInterface=class com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp, type=required, direct=true}, Dependency{anInterface=class com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId, type=required, direct=true}, Dependency{anInterface=class com.google.firebase.abt.component.AbtComponent, type=required, direct=true}, Dependency{anInterface=class android.content.Context, type=required, direct=true}, Dependency{anInterface=interface com.google.firebase.analytics.connector.AnalyticsConnector, type=optional, direct=true}]}: class com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId'
```

I don't know what else to try. Any idea?

Comment: Based on my search, you could try to disable the r8 and use the ProGuard. In Android project properties> Android Options> Code shrinker> ProGuard.

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT I tried that but am still getting the same error.

Comment: Having the same issue and error with Xamarin.Firebase.Ads, indicating that this may be a broader issue with the Firebase component library.